# Разное отображение шрифта в разных браузерах

Tags: html, css

Для меню используется нестандартный шрифт AXP FreeSetC Bold.
Шрифт прогнала через шрифтобелку и подключаю через

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'freesetcregular';
    src: url('../fonts/freesetc-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/freesetc-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/freesetc-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/freesetc-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/freesetc-bold-webfont.svg#freesetcregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

стили элементов меню

```
nav ul li a {
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: -0.1em;
    padding: 25px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #235F79;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'freesetcregular';
    }
```

при этом в хроме меню выглядит так

[image: http://i.imgur.com/hmqQq.png]

а в фф - так

[image]

Можно ли как-то добиться одинакового внешнего вида шрифта?
Как крайний вариант можно сделать меню картинками, но не хотелось бы.
Верстка выложена [здесь](http://web-portfolio1.narod.ru/index7/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что ваш  `letter-spacing: -0.1em;` рассчитывается браузерами по разному. Если в Хроме значение принимает `letter-spacing: -1px;` то в ФФ `letter-spacing: -1.4px;`

Замените `letter-spacing: -0.1em;` на `letter-spacing: -1px;` и будет счастье на вашей улице ))

Comment: да, большое спасибо, получилось!)